# Storing result from a callback to a variable

Tags: java, gwt, programming-languages

How can I save the result of result.getDistance().inMeters() to distance?

```
public class Route {
  private double distance;
  public Route() {
    distance = 0;
    run();
  }

  public void run() {
    Directions.load(query, opts, new DirectionsCallback() {

      public void onFailure(int statusCode) {
       Window.alert("Failed to route locations: " 
         + StatusCodes.getName(statusCode) + " " + statusCode);
      }

      public void onSuccess(DirectionResults result) {
           distance = result.getDistance().inMeters();
      }

    );
  }
  public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
  }
}
```

On my main java file, whenever I do

```
Route route = new Route();
double distance = route.getDistance();
```

distance will always be 0.

Comment: "On my main java file, whenever I do

Route route = new Route();
double distance = route.getDistance();
distance will always be 0."

Of course, since the variable distance is initialized to 0 in the constructor Route();

Comment: Does `Directions.load()` start a new thread? If so you need to wait for it to complete before you get distance.

Answer (score 3):

[@dominic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682263/dominicbri7)'s comment is correct:

> "On my main java file, whenever I do `Route route = new Route(); double distance = route.getDistance();`distance will always be 0." Of course, since the variable distance is initialized to `0` in the constructor `Route()`;

You need to wait for the `onSuccess` callback to execute before `getDistance()` can return a nonzero value. The typical solution to this problem is just executing the code that depends on `getDistance()` inside the callback itself:

```
public void onSuccess(DirectionResults result) {
    distance = result.getDistance().inMeters();
    doStuffThatDependsOn(distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronized block till one of onSuccess or onFailure are called.

in run() method add:

```
synchronized(this) {
    wait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
...
}
```

And in onSuccess and onFailure add:

```
synchronized(Route.class.this) {
    notify();
}
```

Comment: GWT compiles to JavaScript and runs in the browser in a single thread.